# How to find out why openning a Terminal in OS X is very slow sometimes?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, terminal.app

Is there a way to verbosely print everything that gets executed when I open a Terminal in OS X?

Sometimes it takes up to 10 seconds for the Terminal to become ready for interaction and I want to know what's causing this.

Most likely it is something in one of my dot files or as someone had suggested it could be a DNS related issue but either way I want to know the reason for this random slowness and fix it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash`, put

```
set -x
```

in all of your shell startup files. This shell option prints every command that is executed, post-expansion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the time it takes for your shell to source your dotfiles, you can just `time` their execution.

```
time . ~/.bash_profile
```

Rinse and repeat for `.profile` (if you use that instead of `.bash_profile`), `.bashrc` (if you source this from `.bash_profile`*), et cetera. Otherwise, I don't think any system configuration file should be responsible for that.

I've personally found `bash_completion` to take rather long (~300ms) – in my case, this part consumes most of the time it takes up to source my `.bash_profile`.

<sub>* `.bashrc` isn't sourced automatically for new Terminal sessions in OS X, so you'd have to manually specify that anyway.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I was facing the same behavior in my m1 macbook air. Thing is that .zprofile had over a thousand lines of the following:

```
...
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
...
```

I ended up keeping just this at the beginning of the file:

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/edilson/.zprofileeval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

10 seconds to couple of milliseconds =)